# Add trailing slash to hashchange breaks back button

Tags: javascript, hash

I have the following code in my application:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    console.log('hashchange event');

    var hash = window.location.hash;

    var lastChar = hash.substr(-1);

    if(lastChar != '/') {

        // Add trailing slash
        hash = hash.replace(/\/?$/, '/');

        // Update the hash
        window.location.hash = hash;

    }

});
```

If a user tries to mess with the hash of the page or a page is requested with a different hash and doesn't have a trailing slash then it will auto-add one and update the hash.

This is to prevent duplicate urls like: `domain.com/#/home` and `domain.com/#/home/`

However this breaks the back button, because if you try and go back AFTER the hash has been updated, you will end up being sent forward again because it will immediately fix the hash again so you will end up in a loop of NEVER been able to step back (unless you hold down the back button and choose a history entry BEFORE the hash replace happened).

Any ideas on how I could get around this?

Answer (score 4):

One trick is to use `location.replace` to modify the `hash` without changing the history.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    console.log('hashchange event');
    var hash = location.hash,
        lastChar = hash[hash.length - 1];
    if(lastChar !== '/') {
        // Update the hash without changing history
        location.replace(location.href.replace(/\/?$/, '/'));
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be working :) Thanks pal. Nice addition to your rep.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of browser support you need (for example IE < 10) you could try using history.replaceState. The following code worked for me in the console:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){

    console.log('hashchange event');

    var hash = window.location.hash;

    var lastChar = hash.substr(-1);

    if(lastChar != '/') {

        // Add trailing slash
        hash = hash.replace(/\/?$/, '/');

        // Update the hash
        history.replaceState({}, 'hashchange', hash)

    }

});
```

For example with your previous code if I did window.location.hash = 'foo', I would see two hashchange events, then like you said the browser back button will no longer work. With replaceState I see only one hashchange event and the hash will become 'foo/'. Then if I try changing the hash again to 'bar', I will get 'bar/'. Hitting the back button takes me to 'foo/'.

MDN has some nice docs on html5 browser history stuff that could be helpful too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Hope that helps

Comment: Also, if you need good browser support and you're willing to use a plugin, this one looks like it could do the trick: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js (I haven't used it but Modernizr lists it in their docs)